# unwrapping complex JSON in Swift 2

Tags: json, swift2

Im just hitting a mental block!  I appreciate any assistance you may be able to offer in unwrapping the following.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://webapi.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2015-12-28/meetings?jurisdiction=NSW")!    
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let urlContent = data {                
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            print(jsonResult)
            //  Code for unwrapping 'jsonResult'

           //  End of unwrapping 'If you worked it out, thank you!!!!!!!!!
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: what do you mean with "unwrapping"?  What does `jsonResult` yield?

Comment: A string of horse racing data. You might need to update the date value in the url if you cant access it. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

play in playground!

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Foundation

let url = NSURL(string: "https://webapi.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2015-12-28/meetings?jurisdiction=NSW")!
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let urlContent = data {
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            if let meetings = jsonResult["meetings"] as? NSArray {
                if let dateStr = meetings[0]["meetingDate"] as? String {
                    print(dateStr)
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()

// prints
//
// 2015-12-28
```

continue as in this example for each data you need to use ...

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a shot